# Missing value error in the if() condition for R

Tags: r, error-handling, normalization, data-preprocessing

I want to perform log-normalisation on myy data, and since some enteries are 0.0000 in my dataframe I want to put some very small value of the order 1e-7, so that after performing log normalisation, I don't get *-Inf* as the value stored.

I'm writing the following code in my console:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(genes_rpkm_rep_colN))
{
  for(j in 1:ncol(genes_rpkm_rep_colN))
  {
    if(genes_rpkm_rep_colN[i,j] == 0.0000000){
      genes_rpkm_rep_colN[i,j] <- 1e-7      
    }

  }
}
```

I'm encountering the following error while running this piece of code:

```
Error in if (genes_rpkm_rep_colN[i, j] == 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I've put a true/false boolean condition in the `if()` statement, yet the error.

I'm share a small piece of my data below so that you can have a look and check that my data isn't the one causing the error.

```
> dput(genes_rpkm_rep_colN[1:10,1:30])
structure(list(X42MGBA_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0093774, 
3.99494, 0.0208305, 0.0065619, 0.0084466, 0.0085095, 0.0174268, 
0.0233318, 0.0530461, 0.0699613), X8MGBA_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0, 
4.6815, 0.0188461, 0.0118735, 0.0152838, 0.0230965, 0.0157667, 
0.0070364, 0.0319951, 0.101274), A1207_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0432576, 
2.96619, 0.0137272, 0.0259454, 0, 0.0336463, 0.0114842, 0, 0.0553488, 
7.44429), A172_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0194699, 2.92748, 
0.0216248, 0.0272483, 0, 0.0176679, 0.0180913, 0.0080738, 0.0665414, 
0.0387354), AM38_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0115334, 2.69758, 
0.0085399, 0.0322822, 0.0069257, 0, 0.0357226, 0.0063769, 0.0471195, 
0.271525), CAS1_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.10065, 4.8228, 0.0958194, 
0.0469533, 0.0518052, 0.069588, 0.0979765, 0.0556501, 0.117486, 
0.147798), CCFSTTG1_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0440228, 6.04641, 
0.019558, 0.0246441, 0.0158612, 0.0079897, 0.0163623, 0.0073022, 
0.0601819, 0.118238), CH157MN_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0120244, 
3.41429, 0.0053421, 0.0235595, 0.0173293, 0.0043646, 0.0044692, 
0.0139616, 0.0408118, 0.181811), D283MED_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0638066, 
5.12254, 0.0250124, 0.057781, 0.0135231, 0.0272476, 0.0279006, 
0.0124515, 0.0583877, 0.343494), D341MED_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0418829, 
4.97037, 0.0348888, 0.0219808, 0.0377255, 0.0380065, 0.058376, 
0.0217101, 0.0937822, 1.3228), DAOY_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0277923, 
4.16543, 0.051447, 0.0194477, 0.016689, 0.0336267, 0.0602569, 
0.0460997, 0.0633229, 0.317934), DBTRG05MG_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.062215, 
4.22423, 0.0307115, 0.0580469, 0.0622661, 0.012546, 0.0128466, 
0.0171996, 0.72017, 0.192542), DKMG_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0061458, 
2.58862, 0.0546082, 0.0086011, 0.0332147, 0.0446161, 0.0571067, 
0.0866511, 0.0985031, 0.128385), GAMG_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0638691, 
4.18606, 0.023646, 0.0595902, 0.0095882, 0.0676175, 0.0296734, 
0.0264853, 0.0953419, 1.13302), GB1_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0332071, 
4.09682, 0.0122941, 0.0232368, 0.0199406, 0.0100446, 0.0205706, 
0.036721, 0.15393, 8.77573), GI1_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0236971, 
2.99664, 0.0315838, 0.0132657, 0.008538, 0.0344062, 0.0528461, 
0.0196535, 0.0826642, 0.132007), GMS10_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.112392, 
3.29799, 0, 0.0058257, 0.007499, 0.0151096, 0.0232076, 0.0069047, 
0.0392457, 0.0786757), GOS3_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0785394, 
3.06583, 0.0793018, 0.0349735, 0.0128625, 0.0194374, 0.0464408, 
0.0207256, 0.149777, 0.205972), H4_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0412065, 
5.11983, 0.0416065, 0.0209705, 0.0337421, 0.0543895, 0.0417697, 
0.018641, 0.0953581, 0.432261), HS683_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0395662, 
4.82034, 0.0087891, 0.016612, 0.0285111, 0, 0.0294118, 0.0164074, 
0.0708759, 0.240087), IOMMLEE_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0089568, 
3.07764, 0, 0.0188027, 0.0080677, 0.0406391, 0.0083226, 0.0037142, 
0.0295557, 0.178196), KALS1_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0212606, 
3.22541, 0.0094454, 0.0059509, 0.0076601, 0.0154343, 0.0790207, 
0.0105796, 0.0440979, 0.135353), KG1C_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0306739, 
3.25635, 0.0292018, 0.0674589, 0.007894, 0.0397642, 0.0814343, 
0.0036343, 0.107415, 0.248463), KNS42_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0377038, 
2.77745, 0.0598239, 0.0075381, 0.0097032, 0, 0, 0.0044672, 0.0660162, 
0.128592), KNS60_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0308664, 2.75686, 
0.0571377, 0.0359982, 0, 0.0186731, 0.0095603, 0, 0.0606269, 
0.214931), KNS81_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0376095, 4.39526, 
0.041772, 0.0328967, 0.0169382, 0.0341286, 0.0349465, 0.003899, 
0.0864295, 0.0841772), KS1_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0113846, 
1.91478, 0.0252892, 0.0318656, 0.0102545, 0.0413236, 0.0317354, 
0.004721, 0.0295168, 0.18686), LN18_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0159147, 
4.40237, 0, 0.0371213, 0.0191134, 0.0192557, 0.0197172, 0.0219985, 
0.0600177, 0.358841), LN215_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0188976, 
6.19285, 0.0209891, 0, 0, 0.0257228, 0.0175595, 0.0274276, 0.05345, 
0.422964), LN229_CENTRAL_NERVOUS_SYSTEM = c(0.0042589, 4.66724, 
0.0189209, 0.0059603, 0.0153445, 0, 0.0316585, 0.0070643, 0.0602291, 
0.169461)), row.names = c("DDX11L1", "WASH7P", "MIR1302-11", 
"FAM138A", "OR4G4P", "OR4G11P", "OR4F5", "RP11-34P13.7", "CICP27", 
"AL627309.1"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try `df[df == 0] <- 1e-7`. It's no need to use any loop.

Comment: You are testing `genes_rpkm_rep_colN_log`, but I think you meant to test `genes_rpkm_rep_colN`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this without a loop:

```
library(dplyr)
df |> 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(.x == 0.0000000, 1e-7, .x)), 
         across(everything(), ~log(.x), .names = "log_{col}"))
```